# resolveTopDef, TopDefnApp, ResolveTopDefinition?

Tags: f#, quotations

@Tomasp has several blog entries ([here's one](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-quotation-samples.aspx/)) that refer to a way of using `[<ReflectedDefinition>]` and `ResolveTopDefinition` to extract the quotation from a method as an alternative to wrapping the definition in `<@ ... @>` (or is it `<@@ ... @@>`?).

In any case, I can't get any of these things to compile now and I think the features have been changed - but I don't know to what and pretty much the only mentions I find on google of these names are of or related to Tomas's blog and work.

What is the current way?

I've seen Eval.TryGetReflectedDefinition, but that requires a MethodBase and that approach doesn't seem like it should be necessary unless I'm trying to reflect on another/already compiled assembly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API around quotations and reflected method definitions has been changing quite a bit (and I wrote some of the blog posts in the very early days), so this is the most out-of-date part of my blog. Sorry about that!

Anyway, the following simple snippet demonstrates the current API:

```
[<ReflectedDefinition>]
let foo a b = a + b

open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

match <@@ foo 1 2 @@> with
// Matches a call to a static method that is marked as `ReflectedDefinition`
| Patterns.Call(None, DerivedPatterns.MethodWithReflectedDefinition body, args) -> 
    // Return the actual quotation - simply call the body that represents 
    // the function with all the arguments as arguments.
    Expr.Applications(body, args |> List.map (fun a -> [a]))
| e -> e
```

If you're doing lots of quotation processing, then it's probably a good idea to `open` both `Patterns` and `DerivedPatterns` to make the code shorter (but on the other hand,  "dot" makes it easy to explore the modules).

The key thing here is `MethodWithReflectedDefinition` which is a pattern that can match any `MethodInfo` (and there is a similar one for properties) and returns its quotation when it is a method with `ReflectedDefinition` attribute. You can also place the attribute on a module that contains the functions.

Comment: Awesome!  And what if I want to get the same body function without supplying the parameters?  Is that possible?  That is, if I only supply `<@@ foo @@>` to the `match`.

Comment: (Because I want to translate it to another language, supplying in an environment value of a type, instances of which aren't available locally.)

Comment: You can extract the body from `<@@ foo @@>` too - you'd have to look at the quotation this generates and extract the `MethodInfo` that is somewhere there. I think the compiler will actually see this as `<@@ fun a b -> foo a b @@>` so you need `Patterns.Lambdas` first.